# Nameservers setup

Tags: linux, nameserver, domain-registration

I'm going to move to dedicated server from shared hosting.
I setup nameservers on xname.org for my domain, added A record. 
Now I need to change nameservers to ns0.xname.org., ns1.xname.org. But firstly I would like to check somehow that all will work fine after name servers change. Can I check somewhere that setup of nameservers on xname.org is correct?

**Updated according to @Olipro answer**

Here is the result of dig

```
root@lexa-virtual-machine:/var/www# dig @ns1.xname.org uniquemobiles.com.au A

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @ns1.xname.org uniquemobiles.com.au A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17014
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;uniquemobiles.com.au.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
uniquemobiles.com.au.   86400   IN      A       114.112.255.122

;; Query time: 59 msec
;; SERVER: 178.33.255.252#53(178.33.255.252)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 25 16:35:42 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

As I can see A record is correct and all will work fine?

Comment: Without the domain name it's hard to help.

Comment: domain name is uniquemobiles.com.au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend BIND dig.

`dig @ns0.xname.org mydnsrecord.example.com A`

Comment: Seems that you are right. I updated my question, can you tell me if setup of nameservers is correct and I can use them?

Comment: Your current DNS record points to 103.11.207.181 - assuming that it is your intention for the IP to change when you flip nameservers, yes.

Comment: Yes, current nameservers are pointed to 103.11.207.181. So when I will change nameservers to ns1.xname.org, my website will open correctly on 114.112.255.122, correct?

Comment: yes, although you should be aware that the nameserver records for your domain currently have a TTL of 14400 so the switchover will take several hours to actually happen. It would arguably be a good idea to change the IP on the old nameservers if you're able to.

Comment: Do you meen to add A record?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that http://dnscheck.sidn.nl/?test=undelegated would be useful.